# getting an error as cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Tags: numpy

The error in the line cost=float(np.squeeze(cost)), can someone help on this
shape of A2: (1, 10000)
shape of y: (1, 10000)

```
def compute_cost(A2,y,parameters):
m=y.shape[1]
logprobs=y*np.log(A2)+(1-y)*np.log(1-A2)
print(logprobs.shape)
cost=-1/m*np.sum(logprobs)
cost=float(np.squeeze(cost))
assert(isinstance(cost,float))
return cost
```

Comment: cannot reproduce. `1/m*np.sum(logprobs)` already returns a float for randomly generated input y and A2 (type np.ndarray). also, you pass an argument `parameters` to the function which is never used?

Comment: @MrFuppes So there any changes i can do

Comment: can you post the full traceback of the error you get?

Comment: @MrFuppes
<ipython-input-187-9cff5acf4788> in compute_cost(A2, y)
      4     print(logprobs.shape)
      5     cost=-1/m*np.sum(logprobs)
----> 6     cost=float(np.squeeze(cost,axis=0))
      7     assert(isinstance(cost,float))
      8     return cost

D:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
     91             return converter(self.iloc[0])
     92         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
---> 93                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
     95     wrapper.__name__ = "__{name}__".format(name=converter.__name__)

Comment: seems like the error is actually raised by something else; of what `dtype` are y and A2?

Comment: @MrFuppes The dtypes are
y int64
A2 float64

Comment: still cannot reproduce, sry. `cost=-1/m*np.sum(logprobs)` already gives `cost` as a float; the error you get must originate somewhere else I guess. Can you try to present a [mre]? Btw. the indentation of your function is wrong in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The python function `float` cannot be used on a Series (or array).  It's meant to convert a single integer or string to a single float number, if possible.

```
In [67]: S = pd.Series([1,2,3])                                                                      
In [68]: float(S)                                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-c260eee82bbe> in <module>
----> 1 float(S)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in wrapper(self)
    110         if len(self) == 1:
    111             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 112         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    113 
    114     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
In [69]: float(np.array([1,2,3]))                                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-5fadeda48bde> in <module>
----> 1 float(np.array([1,2,3]))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```